# Qual o melhor jeito de raspar o site do Datasus em Python?

Tags: python, aplicação-web, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrapy

O link é esse:
http://tabnet.datasus.gov.br/cgi/tabcgi.exe?sih/cnv/nrbr.def

Estou tentando mandar um POST através do requests com um dicionário contendo as categorias que desejo, mas depois a URL continua estática.

Acha que o Selenium seria mais indicado pra isso? Alguém já fez algo parecido?

Comment: Cara, eu já fiz uma implementação para raspagem de dados, utilizei o scrapy (python). Fica a sugestão.

Answer (score 2):

Não recomendo a utilização do Selenium, pois de acordo com [Sasa Buklijas em "Não utilize Selenium para Web Scraping"](https://hackernoon.com/do-not-use-selenium-for-web-scraping-de90cca7c804) ele afirma que o Selenium não é uma ferramenta especializada de web scraping (técnica de extração de dados utilizada para coletar dados de sites), e sim uma ferramenta para realizar testes automatizados de aplicações web. Recomenda-se a utilização de ferramentas como **Scrapy** ou **Beautiful Soup + Requests**.

O site do Datasus acho difícil a utilização do Selenium pois o site possui muitas caixas de seleção, gerando muitas combinações para conseguir baixar todo conteúdo, será muito trabalhoso fazer isso em Selenium, sendo que existem outras ferramentas melhores para esta finalidade.

Já fiz algo parecido para pegar todos os resultados do Enem utilizando Bash Script e cURL, conforme os passos a seguir:

1. Utilize o Google Chrome
2. Abra o site do Datasus
3. Clique com o botão direito, e selecione "Inspecionar", vai abrir as ferramentas do desenvolvedor à direita do browser.
4. Clique na aba "Network" nas ferramentas de desenvolvedor
5. No site do Datasus à esquerda, selecione as opções, e clique no botão "Mostrar" que aparece no site
6. Nas ferramentas de desenvolvedor clique na requisição enviada ao servidor chamada "tabcgi.exe?sih/cnv/nrbr.def" com o botão DIREITO, selecione COPY -> Copy as...

Dependendo de onde for desenvolver o script, se for em Linux selecione "Copy as cURL (Bash)" se for no Windows "Copy as cURL (cmd)".

Com o comando cURL copiado basta colar no Bash do Linux e ele vai fazer a requisição igual ao Browser. Você pode ir modificando os parâmetros da requisição cURL para ir buscando outras informações do site.

Exemplo abaixo da requisição cURL:

```
curl 'http://tabnet.datasus.gov.br/cgi/tabcgi.exe?sih/cnv/nrbr.def' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Pragma: no-cache' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' \
  -H 'Origin: http://tabnet.datasus.gov.br' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' \
  -H 'Referer: http://tabnet.datasus.gov.br/cgi/tabcgi.exe?sih/cnv/nrbr.def' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7' \
  -H 'Cookie: TS014879da=01e046ca4c72569773aca201f18700eeeba156dca36d80d2164402d50541a167b0fe28c1eed5e284f878cbb97def8098f34d4600bd' \
  --data 'Linha=Macrorregi%E3o_de_Sa%FAde&Coluna=--N%E3o-Ativa--&Incremento=Interna%E7%F5es&Arquivos=nrbr2003.dbf&pesqmes1=Digite+o+texto+e+ache+f%E1cil&SMunic%EDpio=1&pesqmes2=Digite+o+texto+e+ache+f%E1cil&SCapital=1&pesqmes3=Digite+o+texto+e+ache+f%E1cil&SRegi%E3o_de_Sa%FAde_%28CIR%29=1&pesqmes4=Digite+o+texto+e+ache+f%E1cil&SMacrorregi%E3o_de_Sa%FAde=TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__&pesqmes5=Digite+o+texto+e+ache+f%E1cil&SMicrorregi%E3o_IBGE=TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__&pesqmes6=Digite+o+texto+e+ache+f%E1cil&SRegi%E3o_Metropolitana_-_RIDE=TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__&pesqmes7=Digite+o+texto+e+ache+f%E1cil&STerrit%F3rio_da_Cidadania=TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__&pesqmes8=Digite+o+texto+e+ache+f%E1cil&SMesorregi%E3o_PNDR=TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__&SAmaz%F4nia_Legal=TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__&SSemi%E1rido=TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__&SFaixa_de_Fronteira=TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__&SZona_de_Fronteira=TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__&SMunic%EDpio_de_extrema_pobreza=TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__&SCar%E1ter_atendimento=TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__&SRegime=TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__&pesqmes16=Digite+o+texto+e+ache+f%E1cil&SCap%EDtulo_CID-10=TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__&pesqmes17=Digite+o+texto+e+ache+f%E1cil&SLista_Morb__CID-10=TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__&pesqmes18=Digite+o+texto+e+ache+f%E1cil&SFaixa_Et%E1ria_1=3&pesqmes19=Digite+o+texto+e+ache+f%E1cil&SFaixa_Et%E1ria_2=TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__&SSexo=TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__&SCor%2Fra%E7a=TODAS_AS_CATEGORIAS__&zeradas=exibirlz&formato=prn&mostre=Mostra' \
  --compressed \
  --insecure
```

No campo --data você tem ir alterando os valores para todas possibilidades e ir fazendo novas requisições cURL até baixar toda as informações do site.

O retorno das requisições cURL vem em HTML, se preferir remover todas tags HTML pode utilizar um pipe com o lynx.

```
$ curl <comando> | lynx --dump -stdin > resultado1.txt
```